# How to know why starting such version of ant?

Tags: java, unix, ant

I want to start ant.sh script with specific target

```
./ant.sh -verbose test
```

and I get

```
Apache Ant version 1.5.4 compiled on August 12 2003
```

but if I look at ant_home, I see

```
/opt/checkout/dev> echo $ANT_HOME
/opt/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0
```

Here is a script which whom I am starting ant:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx512m -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl -classpath $TEST_HOME/implementation/lib/dbflux3.1.5.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$CLASSPATH org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml $*
```

Here is strings in classpath related to ant:

```
:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ant.jar /opt/checkout/implementation/lib/ant.jar
```

Why I getting ant 1.5 not 1.7?

Thanks.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run that? Note that you seem to have *three* different Ant installations there - `/opt/Oracle/...`, `/opt/IBM/...`, `/opt/checkout/...`

Comment: I run ant.sh from /opt/checkout/dev

Comment: Okay, so your classpath doesn't mention `/opt/Oracle/Middleware` - but it *does* mention `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer`... so my guess is that that's where it's picking up Ant from.

Comment: And should I remove /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer from classpath? Is it correct?

Comment: Well we don't know why it's there to start with. I can't really advise you on how to configure your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unix 'which' command to identify the path to the binary that will be executed according to your $PATH.  For example:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Therefore, you might try embedding the use of 'which' in your .sh script to see which specific binary is being invoked, and this might help you to debug your problem. For example:

```
echo `which ant`
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but my reputation is too low to do this. I need as minimum 15 reputation.

Comment: Ah, no worries.  I'm new too and just learning how to use the site!